# AX2012 - ListPageGrid does not update

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm having a lot of trouble adding another field to a ListPageGrid in one of my Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 - R3 environments.

For some background information, I have 4 different environments which I'm trying to do this on. 2 successful, 2 unsuccessful. Environments are like so:

**Environment A: MS AX 2012 R3 - Demo Data.** I follow the steps below and can successfully add a new field to the ListPageGrid or swap the order of them.

**Environment B: MS AX 2012 R3 - Client Data #1**. I follow the exact same steps here and am not able to see any changes.

**Environment C: MS AX 2012 R3 - Client Data #1** - Copy. This environment is essentially a clone of environment B, it has very similar data. I'm not able to see changes here either.

**Environment D: MS AX 2012 - Client Data #2**. This is not an R3 environment, and contains data that is different from environment C and B.

Now, here are the steps that I follow to make the changes:

1. Open the form (in my case, **ReqTransPoListPage**)
2. Designs -> Design -> [Grid:ListPageGrid]
3. I would then open the datasource attached to the grid in a new window (in my case, **RecPO**)
4. Drag the field from the window to the list of current fields
5. Save/Compile the form

In environments A and D this is successful, in environments B and C this is not.
I have also tried just simply re-arranging the order of currently existing fields in the grid, and again same results in the same environments.

When I successfully add a new field in environments A and D, I'm able to see them right away and when I right click -> personalize, I can see the new field I have added. In environments C and D, I cannot. It just sits there under the grid without being visible anywhere else. I can scramble the order of the fields too and that has no effect on the form.

To confirm that I am in fact looking at the right form, I took one of the currently existing fields and gave it a label. To my surprise, this worked. I can give currently existing fields a label, but I cannot swap the order, add anything new, or delete them.

Seeing this pattern, one can conclude that it's some kind of configuration in my environments B and C, since they are very very similar.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I cannot make these changes or what I should be checking to see if it's misconfigured? I've honestly spent almost a full day on this and it's getting really frustrating.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

(I can look up and provide any further information if necessary. I've checked the data source of the grid, the query associated with it, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try closing all forms and refreshing your usage data.

In your dev environment, go to: Tools>Options>Usage data(button) and click the "Reset" button. This will clear all of your saved selections/queries/personalizations/etc. but I'm assuming this will solve your random form visibility issue.

You could also find the form in the "form setup" tab and delete that if you want to be a little bit more surgical. Clearing usage data is normally my go-to for weird UX issues.

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues with form mods not showing up, usually for me it ends up being a usage data issue. Try clearing your usage data:

- go to Tools > options from the development window
- click the usage data button in the dialog box toolbar
- Open the "All usage data" tab, and use wildcards (*RecPo*) in the Element name field to find all usage data that pertains to your form and data sources
- Use Ctrl+A to select them all, then Alt+F9 to delete them. Close and recompile the form, and hopefully your changes will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Does the grid in B and C have a value in the `DataGroup` attribute of the grid control?

If so, any field you add to the grid is discarded.

Comment: As Jan has indicated, perhaps the field has not been added to a table DataGroup, which the form parent control may be referencing: [explanation for user1300922](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/115271.aspx).
I also assume that the field you are attempting to add to the form is not linked to any specific [country functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404126.aspx) or [configuration key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378074.aspx) that is activated on some AX services but not others.

Comment: Unfortunately, the DataGroup attribute is empty in all environments.